# AddLast method not working in list class

Tags: java, list

So I'm trying to create a simple list class that implements the addFIrst and addLast algorithm to be more specific like this:

```
public class Node {

    private int item;
    private Node link;

    public Node(int item, Node link)
    {
        this.item=item;
        this.link=link;
    }

    public int getItem()
    {
        return item;
    }

    public Node getLInk()
    {
        return link;
    }

    public void setItem(int item)
    {
        this.item=item;
    }

    public void setLink(Node link)
    {
        this.link=link;
    }
}

public class LIsta {

    private Node head;

    public LIsta()
    {
        head=null;
    }

    public void insertFirst(int item)
    {
        Node n=new Node(item, head);
        head=n;
    }

    public void insertLast(int item)
    {
        Node temp=head;
        while(temp!=null) temp=temp.getLInk();
        Node n=new Node(item, null);
        temp.setLink(n);
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Node temp=head;
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.getItem());
            temp=temp.getLInk();
        }
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LIsta list=new LIsta();
        list.insertFirst(5);
        list.insertFirst(3);
        list.insertFirst(2);
        list.insertLast(8);
        list.Print();
    }

}
```

However it gives me an error whenever I try to call the `insertLast()` method more specifically in the line: 
`temp.setLink(n);`

It says: Null pointer access. The variable temp can only be a null at this point. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: What about the error message do you not understand? You loop `while(temp!=null)`, so once your loop is done `temp` can only be null

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over the links until `temp` becomes `null`, and at this point you can't do anything with the `temp` variable. You need to find the last link (i.e. the last non-null `Node` whose `getLInk()` is `null`).

```
public void insertLast(int item)
{
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node(item, null);
    } else {
        Node temp=head;
        while(temp.getLInk() != null) temp=temp.getLInk();
        Node n=new Node(item, null);
        temp.setLink(n);
    }
}
```